# Add middleware to controller in __construct in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-middleware

I am trying to assign a middleware in __construct of a controller based on [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers) but it throws the follwing error:

```
BadMethodCallException
Method App\Http\Controllers\MyController::middlware does not exist.
```

that is my controller class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class MyController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('myauth');
    }

    /** something */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('test.hi', ['name' => 'Moh']);
    }
}
```

And here is the middleware code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class myauth
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        echo time().'<br>';
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Laravel version: 6.5.2

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Middleware can be specified within controller's constructor

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

For whole controller:

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

Only for a particular action:

```
$this->middleware('auth')->only('index');
```

For whole controller except particular action:

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except('store');
```

Answer (score 4):

The function is `middleware`, you have a typo, missing an `e`.

Comment: Thanks, I dont know why I did not realize that

Answer (score 0):

Firstly ask to you, Your error is `middlware` name is incoorect you missed `e` after that check the below middleware process.

Laravel Middleware - Middleware acts as a middleman between a request and a response.

Firstly goto project folder and open cmd and use this command

```
php artisan make:middleware MiddlewareName
```

after that go to App\Http\kernel.php and add one lines on $routeMiddleware

```
'user_block' => \App\Http\Middleware\MiddlewareName::class
```

After that goto your middleware
In handle function (write your own middleware code)

In routes use your middleware -

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['user_block']],
    function () {
Route::get('/logout', array('uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@logout'));
});
```

If you used this middleware in specific controller in __construct in any  controller just write a line

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;

class UserController extends Controller {

 public function __construct() {

    $this->middleware('user_block');
 }
}
```

If you want this middleware for just one action in the controller you can add this middleware to the route :

```
Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@login')->middleware('user_block');
```

If you used this middleware in specific controller in specific 1-2 function just write this line in __construct functiono in controller

```
public function __construct()
{
   $this->middleware('user_block')->only(['login','register']);
}
```